# Requesting Permissions at Run Time in c/c++(ndk native) or Application class

Tags: android, c++, security, android-ndk

I want to get android dynamic rights, but I can not get or create an activity.
It is trying to use the Application class. Code-

```
public class Myap extends Application 
{
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS");
        intent.putExtra("android.content.pm.extra.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_NAMES",new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE });
        intent.setPackage("com.android.packageinstaller");
        startActivity(intent, null);
    }
}
```

Or call ndk reflection, I do not know how to do.